# Why is this expression inside a for-loop acting weird in R?

Tags: r

I'm running a for loop with i from 3 to 21. And I'm printing 5 values of 'i' using its index:

```
for (i in 3:21 )
{ 
  print(i)
  print(i-2 : i+2)

}
```

The actual output is:

```
[1] 3
[1] 3 2
[1] 4
[1] 4 3 2
[1] 5
[1] 5 4 3 2
[1] 6
[1] 6 5 4 3 2
[1] 7
[1] 7 6 5 4 3 2
[1] 8
[1] 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 and etc
```

But I was expecting:

```
3
1 2 3 4 5
4
4 5 6 7 8 
5
5 6 7 8 9 
6
6 7 8 9 10 and etc
```

I guess I'm not using the index properly.. Where did I go wrong??

Comment: You need to use brackets: `(i-2) : (i+2)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use brackets around the terms in the range:

```
for (i in 3:21) {
    print(i)
    print((i-2) : (i+2))
}
```

Observe this:

```
> 1 - 2 : 1 + 2
 [1] 1 2
```

This is actually the same as:

```
> 1 - c(2, 1) + 2
 [1] 1 2
```

In vector pseudo-notation:

```
[1 , 1] - [2, 1] + [2, 2]
[-1, 0] + [2, 2]
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Order of Operations**

You were looking for:

```
for (i in 3:21 ) { 
        print(i)
        print((i-2) : (i+2)) 
    }
[1] 3
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
[1] 4
[1] 2 3 4 5 6
[1] 5
[1] 3 4 5 6 7 ...
```

A simpler example may be instructive:

```
> 1 + 1:3
[1] 2 3 4
> (1 + 1):3
[1] 2 3
```